# Only 16 colors for CColorDialog?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog

Someone knows some way of putting only 16 colors in the `CColorDialog` of Visual Studio C++ when it is opened?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's possible with the standard MFC `CColorDialog`.

But if you really only need 16 colors, wouldn't it make more sense to use something more simple like a combo box to pick a color, instead of a full dialog?

[Here's a Code Project article with an example implementation of a Color Picker Combo Box](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/colourpickercb.aspx):

[image: screenshot]